# Error message - Alert Message Not Appearing

Tags: firebase, flutter, signing

I placing on the interface a message to provide information to users on errors in logging or signing up.

The error does not provide a bug and the application continues to run.

However, the message of error or the status is not passed on to the widget _showAlert which does not appear.

```
    _signup() async {
    AuthNotifier authNotifier = Provider.of<AuthNotifier>(context, listen: false);
            {
      setState(() {
      });
      final status =
          await  signup(_user, authNotifier);
                if (status == AuthResultStatus.successful) {
                // Navigate to success screen
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
          (r) => false);
      } else {
        final errorMsg = AuthExceptionHandler.generateExceptionMessage(status);
        _showAlert(errorMsg);
      }
  }
}

  _showAlert(errorMsg) {
    if (errorMsg != null) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.error_outline),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: AutoSizeText(
                errorMsg,
                maxLines: 3,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    errorMsg = null;
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return SizedBox(
      height: 0,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a Widget not showing a Dialog. To show a Dialog try this

```
_showAlert(errorMsg, BuildContext context) {
  if (errorMsg != null) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          Dialog(
            child: Container(
              // ...
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks DM_tr, I wanted to include it in the Interface without using the Dialog. I will keep it for the time being.

Comment: Have a look at this package https://pub.dev/packages/get. It may be helpful